# How to call describe-function for current-word in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to write an Emacs function that calls `describe-function` for `current-word`. And if there is no function named `current-word` then it calls `describe-variable`.

I tried to write it, but I couldn't even call `describe-function` for `current-word`...

```
(defun describe-function-or-variable ()
(interactive)
(describe-function `(current-word)))
```

How can I write it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(defun describe-function-or-variable ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (intern-soft (current-word))))
    (cond ((null sym)
           "nothing")
          ((functionp sym)
           (describe-function sym))
          (t
           (describe-variable sym)))))
```

Comment: Cool stuff - the result of current-word needs to be converted to a symbol (via `intern-soft`) before describe-function will work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more general function:

```
(defun describe-function-or-variable ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (intern-soft (current-word))))
    (unless
        (cond ((null sym))
              ((not (eq t (help-function-arglist sym)))
               (describe-function sym))
              ((boundp sym)
               (describe-variable sym)))
      (message "nothing"))))
```

It works for special forms, e.g. `and`, as well as for macros, e.g. `case`.
It also makes sure that the varible is bound, before trying to describe it.

Comment: This function seems handier than my idea. Thanks!